# Who was the Philosopher who said to jump into the fire if you think it is not real?

Tags: hume, skepticism, locke

Just as the title says. There was a philosopher who said that you should jump into a fire if you think it might not exist and see how it goes. I cannot find it on google, maybe I am typing in the wrong keywords. I think it might have been Locke or Hume.

Comment: "I refute it THUS" is Bishop Barkley's famous line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

> The celebrated Arab commentator Avicenna (ibn Sīnā, 980–1037)
>   confronts the LNC [Law of Noncontradiction] skeptic...: “As for the obstinate, he must be plunged into
>   fire, since fire and non-fire are identical. Let him be beaten, since
>   suffering and not suffering are the same. Let him be deprived of food
>   and drink, since eating and drinking are identical to abstaining”
>   (Metaphysics I.8, 53.13–15).

Source: Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy > Contradiction > Section 1. LNC [Law of Noncontradiction] as Indemonstrable.